# How to choose optimal groups based on Average in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am trying to optimize the following problem based on the data below:

- Create optimal groups based on the **minimum** average distance in each group
- groups must have >= 3 orders in them
- groups should contain orders in the sequence they appear. They should be **consecutive**. For example, [01, 02, and 03] can a group, but the next group must start with [04, 05, 06, ... 0n].

| order | distance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 6 | 10 |
| 7 | 9 |
| 8 | 15 |
| 9 | 11 |
| 10 | 12 |
| 11 | 13 |
| 12 | 14 |
| 13 | 10 |
| 14 | 5 |
| 15 | 11 |
| 16 | 7 |
| 17 | 15 |
| 18 | 10 |
| 19 | 12 |
| 20 | 12 |

I have thought about creating a rolling average and then using that to determine when to cutoff to make a group, but there are some flaws in that and performance might not be the greatest if the data expands. What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: "Create optimal groups based on the average distance in each group" - **what does "based on" mean**? For the example data, **what should the result be, and why**? "groups should contain orders in the sequence they appear. For example, [O1, O2, and O3] can a group, but [O3, O6, and O10] could not be a group." - This does not make sense, because 3, 6 and 10 are in ascending order. Did you mean, that they should be **consecutive**?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Optimal would be the minimum average of each group. The groups must contain consecutive orders. Meaning that if the first group is (O1, O2 and O3) the next group must start with O4 and contain O5, O6… On. I hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: question has been edited to reflect that groups must have >= 3 members, not >3.

Comment: I doubt that linear programming will be able to express this problem. Probably write a direct DP algo. Hopefully at most O(n²). The only way for this to reasonably scale would be a C impl. I'll try this later.